# how to get the first x number of characters in a variable in shell?

Tags: shell

I have: `var=helloworld`. How would I be able to get the first 5 characters, `hello`, using var?
I have tried: `$echo {var:0:5}` but I get "Bad substitution" error message.

Comment: I am running this using sh filename.sh in ubuntu

Comment: do `echo ${var:0:5}`, if this does not help, you may need to provide which shell you are using by doing `echo $SHELL`

Comment: /bin/bash, Tried using echo ${var:0:5, but still get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${var:0:5}` is a bash extension which isn't available in `sh`. You could use the following instead:

```
$ export var=helloworld
$ echo $(echo $var | head -c 5)
```

Output:

```
hello
```